# Windows 7: problem with TeXnicCenter, MiKTeX2.9

Tags: pdftex, miktex, windows, texniccenter

Please help! They have updated my computer to Windows 7, and I have tried to reinstall MiKTeX2.9 and TeXnicCenter. When I run a LaTeX program, it tries to install 412 files from CTAN, and I get the error:

> pdflatex.exe: A timeout was reached while receiving data from the server

And then I get a LaTeX error that `pgfcore.sty` was not found.

Is it some permissions problem with Windows 7? I have administrative privileges that I could use, but I don't seem to be prompted for my password...

This is driving me crazy! Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Fiona, [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043)! I removed the sign-off, as your user name and badge are automatically included anyway.

Comment: Just as a single data point: The combination of Windows 7, MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter (Alpha 4) is running nicely here. Try Ulrike's suggestions, if they are not enough I would completely remove MiKTeX and reinstall the full version.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that it is due to permissions problems. The message says "timeout" and this indicates a connection problem. It could mean that the server/repository you are trying to use is simply down (that happens). But it also could be due to a proxy or a VPN-tunnel (I can't install packages on my work PC when I'm connected to our intranet).

Try to install the pgf-package directly with the package manager. Try different repositories (menu repository). If both doesn't work: Get from CTAN the files

```
systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma
systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma
systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/pgf.tar.lzma
```

and perhaps other package from `systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/`. Put them all in an empty folder outside your miktex. Then use the package manager to install them by using the folder as "local repository".