# Install pbox with MikTex 2.9

Tags: installing, miktex

I'm trying to install the pbox package on my MiKTeX 2.9 installation, and failing miserably.  The miktex package manager fails with the message "[Remote file not found](http://pastebin.com/JnhrPF09)". I got the package from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pbox and tried to make it, but it attempts to run `/usr/bin/install` which isn't on my Windows machine.

What should I do?  Is anyone else able to install pbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any extra binaries to install such a package. Since you have the files run tex (or latex) on `pbox.ins` this will input `pbox.dtx` and generate `pbox.sty` which is the package file you are after. If it is in the current directory it should just work with your document.
You can latex `pbox.dtx` to get the documentation if you do not already have it (the ready made pdf is already on ctan).

Comment: That's excellent news, I'll give it a whirl.  How do I make it so that I don't have to have the `.sty` in my PWD?

Comment: that would depend on how miktex manages TEXINPUTS but I don't use miktex, but actually if you want that it's probably best to fix the package manager install then miktex will "know" it is there, and handle future updates more cleanly. I gave the answer I did as often it's useful to know that packages not needing fonts etc don't really _need_ _installation_ you just need a local copy of the file.

Answer (score 3):

I just installed pbox with the miktex package manager without any problems. I used the repository at the fu berlin.

Comment: Okay, so it must be an installation problem on my end.  After `pdflatex.exe: Remote file not found` I get `! LaTeX Error: File 'pbox.sty' not found.`  Thanks for testing that for me.

Comment: I just saw in your link that you are probably using the portable version of miktex. I don't know much about this version. Your problem could be due to a broken repository. So at first try to switch to another one. If this fails try to install from a local folder see my answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45653/windows-7-problem-with-texniccenter-miktex2-9

Comment: Well, happy me for descriptive directory names :) . I was able to install a dependency of pbox (I forgot what it's called) and I've installed a number of other packages without issue.  I've tried lots of repository servers. I've tried to install from a local folder (get from ctan, then run `make`) but `make` tries to run `/usr/bin/something` which I don't have.  I recently thought that I should try the posix windows subsystem to see if I can get it to work. Anyway, I compiled the `.sty` and placed in my local directory. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `make`? That's certainly not the correct way on a windows system. Use the package manager and choose the folder with the two miktex-zz...-files and the `pbox.tar.lzma` as local repository.