# Error: File 'pdfpages.sty' not found

Tags: packages, miktex, pdfpages

I'm trying to compile simple thesis example using TexMaker with MiKTeX 2.9. I need *pdfpages* package in order to include pdf as the title page. Without the following line the code compiles fine:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

With this line, every time I try to compile I get the following window:

[image]

I tried many different repositories, but it always ends up with

```
Error: File 'pdfpages.sty' not found. ...
```

So I decided to install it manually, downloaded this package: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages

I've uncompressed the package in the following directory: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdfpages` and then I run these commands from that directory:

```
> latex pdfpages.ins
> latex pdfpages.dtx
```

After that, more files were created in that directory (including **pdfpages.sty**).
But TexMaker still can't detect those files. Still shows me the "Package Installation window".

Minimum example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdf{title_page.pdf}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I really couldn't find any solution to this problem in Google nor in StackExchange database. How to get it working?

Comment: Did you run "mktexlsr"? See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows

Comment: You must update the FNDB (in admin mode) if you put files in this location. I can't say why installation doesn't work, but instead of manual installation I suggest to first try to set up a local repository: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45653/windows-7-problem-with-texniccenter-miktex2-9/45665#45665

Comment: In your MWE, you're calling `\includepdf` in the preamble.  That should be in the body of the document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you make your comment here into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You must update the FNDB (in admin mode) if you put files in this location. I can't say why installation doesn't work, but instead of manual installation I suggest to first try to set up a local repository: [Windows 7: problem with TeXnicCenter, MiKTeX2.9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45653/windows-7-problem-with-texniccenter-miktex2-9/45665#45665)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem except I was using WinEdt rather than TexMaker. Here is what I did. I simply close WinEdt. Then right click on WinEdt icon and then select "Run as administrator". Then compile your file as usual. It should go through the instalation without any error.