# Pdfpages.sty not found - Windows

Tags: miktex, pdfpages

This question is a follow-up question in regards to this topic: [Error: File 'pdfpages.sty' not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98627/error-file-pdfpages-sty-not-found/)

The following is just a copy paste of my question asked in that topic:

> I am so so sorry for asking this question, but I seem to feel as if this is only for Linux users? I cannot for the life of me get pdfpages to work on Windows, and pdfpages.sty never ever seems to be popping up.
>
> I've been scrolling through the depths of the interwebs now for hours trying to find a decent answer and I always seem to be coming back to this one.
>
> ```
> > latex pdfpages.ins
> > latex pdfpages.dtx
> ```
>
> The above seems to be for Ubuntu? It is years since I last used it, and I cannot really recall anything at all. I would appreciate any answer in regards to this.
>
> PS: I've extracted the pdfpages.tds.zip to its appropriate folders, but still there's no 'pdfpages.sty' file.
>
> Best regards

First off, I'll have to admit that I've just recently started using LaTeX, and Pdfpages would be the first 'package' that I would be installing. I followed the descriptions on [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows), but I seem to be failing at getting a `pdfpages.sty` file. I installed it using the `.zip` files (`pdfpages.tds.zip`).

I have also run the `mktexslr`, `texhash` etc. While also having refreshed the FNDB.

I would appreciate any type of help, and I am sorry for asking something that might feel like a dumb question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) it might be best to use the package manager instead, as detailed in tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution

Comment: The main question is why do you want to install manually? Why don't you use the package manager of miktex?

Comment: Thank you for the help. 

Ulrike Fischer: I were unable to find pdfpages as part of the MikTex package. I were unaware of the package manger. I will take a further look at that one. Thank you.

Comment: I tried out the MikTex package manager, and thank you so much for mentioning that one! Wow. It was a cake walk! Thank you again :)

Comment: The package manager suggestion helped me too. It turned out my package manager was using an outdated repository, and that was causing problems with a couple of updates, including pdfpages.sty